# How to get item from QListWidget which was clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 2 groups of lists, one containing 4 QListWidgets(group A) and the other containing only one(group B).

I want to be able to transfer the list items from one group to another, but when I pass the item, something is not working correctly.

Snippet of my code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    #some functions
    def newTeam(self):
        #some code here
        self.fill()
        self.listWidget_2.doubleClicked.connect(self.item)
        self.listWidget_3.doubleClicked.connect(self.item)
        self.listWidget_4.doubleClicked.connect(self.item)
        self.listWidget_5.doubleClicked.connect(self.item)

    def item(self, i):
        self.listWidget.addItem(i.selectedItems())
```

I am guessing I am not passing the list item correctly. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'QModelIndex' object has no attribute 'selectedItems'
```

Comment: `addItem(i.data())`

Comment: @ekhumoro where is the documentation for this? also, Is there any way to find out which list from group A sent the data to the other group, so I can send it back?

Comment: Qt docs: [doubleClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked), [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html), [self.sender()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender).